# Intuition modular equivalence of elements in general groups with element in subgroup (Herstein)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, motivation

> Let $G$ be a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$; for $a,b \in G$ we say $a$ is congurent to $b \mod H$, written as $a \equiv b \mod H$ if $ab^{-1} \in H$
>
> Herstein, *Topics in abstract algebra*, page 34.

What is the motivation behind the above definition?

**My thoughts:**

I am guessing it is doing something with the fact that a subgroup divides the group into a union of disjoint cosets of that subgroup.  In modular arithmetic we say equivalence if remainders are same.. but I am having a hard time understanding in what sense the elements are thought of remainders here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual notion of congruence in integers says that $a\equiv b \bmod n$ if and only $n\mid (a-b)$, or $a-b\in n\Bbb Z$.

If we take $G=(\Bbb Z,+)$ and $H=n\Bbb Z$,
then $ab^{-1}=a-b$ and we can rewrite this as
$$
a\equiv b \mod H \Longleftrightarrow ab^{-1}\in H.
$$
This is a motivation to define this in general.

Actually, many concepts of group theory can be illustrated with the group of integers and this often has a nice interpretation from elementary number theory.